# Inaccurate data gets punched to Heroku PostgreSQL table

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, flask-sqlalchemy

I am learning Flask/SqlAlchemy by making an app myself, however I have noticed sometimes inaccurate data gets punched , See the DataClip [here](https://dataclips.heroku.com/jbmicmbgcqvzajccuuziqwscqrvo-visitor-info) this data gets generated by visiting this [page](http://selflearning.herokuapp.com/)

In the dataclip entry with `visitorId` `N4PT3R0ZQ` is incorrect.i.e I opened the page in Windows phone by typing the URL but the data that got punched is iPhone on which I was viewing the dataclip page or I had visited the page in past.

Here is the code that does update in this table `visitor`.

```
def updateOrInsertToTable(user_agent, visitorInfo):
    """ Updates the table if visitor id exists else insert for new visitor
        Arguments: 
            user_agent (request.user_agent): request.user_agent object
            visitorInfo (dict): key value pair of visitor information 
    """
    visitorId =  visitorInfo["visitorId"]
    visitorIp = visitorInfo["clientIP"]
    language = visitorInfo["language"]
    referrer = visitorInfo["referrer"]
    coord_errorcode = visitorInfo.get("coord_errorcode", None)
    cl_lat = visitorInfo.get("cl_lat", 0.0)
    cl_lng = visitorInfo.get("cl_lng", 0.0)
    tz = _utils.getTimezoneFromIP(visitorIp)
    dtWithZone = _datetime.now(pytz.timezone(tz))
    visitorModel = Visitor(
        user_agent.platform,
        user_agent.browser, 
        dtWithZone, visitorId, 
        cl_lat, cl_lng,
        language, referrer,
        user_agent.version, 
        visitorIp,
        tz
    )
    existing = visitorModel.query.get(visitorId)

    if existing:
        existing.version = user_agent.version
        existing.cl_lat = float(cl_lat)
        existing.cl_lng = float(cl_lng)
        existing.ip = visitorIp
        existing.language = language
        existing.referrer = referrer
        existing.count = existing.count + 1
        existing.coord_errorcode = coord_errorcode
        existing.visitdatetime = dtWithZone
        db.session.commit()
    else:
        columnValues = {
            "platform" : user_agent.platform,
            "browser" : user_agent.browser,
            "visitorId" : visitorId,
            "cl_lat" : cl_lat,
            "cl_lng" : cl_lng,
            "language" : user_agent.language,
            "referrer" : referrer,
            "version" : user_agent.version,
            "count" : 1,
            "coord_errorcode": coord_errorcode,
            "ip" : visitorIp,
            "visitdatetime" : dtWithZone,
            "timezone": tz
        }
        insertIntoTable(dtWithZone, 'visitor', columnValues)



def insertIntoTable(dtWithZone, tableName, columValues):
    """ Insert into table with provided date time and time zone information.
    """
    db_uri = app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]
    engine = create_engine(db_uri, connect_args={"options": "-c timezone={}".format(dtWithZone.timetz().tzinfo.zone)})
    meta = MetaData(engine, reflect=True)
    table = meta.tables[tableName]
    ins = table.insert().values(**columValues)
    conn = engine.connect()
    conn.execute(ins)
    conn.close()
```

Is there anything wrong with my approach? or am I totally doing it wrong?

Comment: What data is inaccurate?

Comment: Sorry , I have updated the post. entry with `visitorId`  `N4PT3R0ZQ`